# execution time of release build in VS2008 IDE vs. direct execution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

When I've built a project in release mode in VS2008. The execution time of running the project from the IDE(project > debug > start new instance) is much faster than running the exe(In my case, 80 seconds and 200 seconds). What could be the reason for this? Can I speeden up the direct execution somehow?

p.s. I had asked this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699245/vc-differences-in-runtimes-of-release-build) but dint get a reply.

Comment: possible duplicate of [vc++: differences in runtimes of release build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699245/vc-differences-in-runtimes-of-release-build)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as i know there is no such thing as "speed up the execution"
but there are lots of factors that help in starting the application
such as memory utilization, CPU usage, ... etc
so what are you asking about might be that visual c starts new processes using direct system calls
instead of explorer ones, not as much performance change .. but can be really seen using a memory leak detector, .. not to check on memory .. but to start an application 1000 times in explorer and 1000 times in command line or memory leak detector
only then you'll notice the difference

PS: the application still passes the antivirus/antispyware tests before it runs, but some older detection methods fail to monitor the system calls for execution, or they tend to ignore the calls by system

PPS: try to check on optimization if you really care about speed, try out the O3 and remove all symbols